# Customize option - add two image uploader under same section

Tags: customization

To add upload option, i added this code on function page:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'custom_logo_uploader' );
function custom_logo_uploader($wp_customize) {

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'upload_custom_logo', array(
        'title'          => 'Logo',
        'description'    => 'Display a custom logo?',
        'priority'       => 25,
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'custom_logo', array(
        'default'        => '',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'custom_logo', array(
        'label'   => 'Custom logo',
        'section' => 'upload_custom_logo',
        'settings'   => 'custom_logo',
    ) ) );
}
```

my question is how can i add add multiple picture option in the same section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after searching whole i got solution. add a new setting and add a new control. Inside of control, add new

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'custom_logo_uploader' );
function custom_logo_uploader($wp_customize) {

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'upload_custom_logo', array(
        'title'          => 'Logo',
        'description'    => 'Display a custom logo?',
        'priority'       => 25,
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'custom_logo', array(
        'default'        => '',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'custom_logo', array(
        'label'   => 'Custom logo',
        'section' => 'upload_custom_logo',
        'settings'   => 'custom_logo',
    ) ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'custom_logo2', array(
        'default'        => '',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'custom_logo2', array(
        'label'   => 'Custom logo',
        'section' => 'upload_custom_logo', // put the name of whatever section you want to add your settings
        'settings'   => 'custom_logo2',
    ) ) );
}
```

sorry if i confuse with my bad English. :(